# Modify bash variable with sed

Tags: bash, sed

Why doesn't the follow bash script work? I would like it to output
two lines like this:

```
XXXXXXX
YYYYYYY
```

It works if I change the sed line to use a filename instead of the variable, but I want to use the variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$(echo -e '=======\n-------\n')

for sym in = -; do
  if [ "$sym" == '-' ]; then
    replace=Y
  else
    replace=X
  fi

  printf "%s\n" "s/./$replace/g"
done | sed -f- <<<"$input"
```

Comment: If you use a file that contains what `input` contains and use that instead of the here-string, do you really get your desired output, and not all `Y`?

Comment: You are piping and redirecting stdin at the same time. You can only do one since they both override stdin.

Comment: Why not use tr (or sed, awk, ,...) -  `echo "$input" | tr '=-' 'XY'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're giving sed *two* sources to read standard input from: the for loop that is fed through the pipe, and the variable coming through the here-string. As it turns out, the here-string gets precedence and sed complains that there are extra characters after a command (`=` is a command).

Instead of a here-string, you could use process substitution:

```
for sym in = -; do
    if [ "$sym" == '-' ]; then
        replace=Y
    else
        replace=X
    fi

    printf "%s\n" "s/./$replace/g"
done | sed -f- <(printf '%s\n' '=======' '-------')
```

You'll notice that the output isn't what you want, though, namely

```
YYYYYYY
YYYYYYY
```

This is because the sed script you end up with looks like this:

```
s/./X/g
s/./Y/g
```

No matter what you do first, the last command replaces everything with `Y`.